# MVC: How to get date time value to edit

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I want to set editable a date time in Edit page. As you can in the image the other datas shown in the fields, date time value is not shown. Here is my code to show date time value :`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CommunicationTime, new { Value = Model.CommunicationTime, type = "date" })`

[image]

I am sure of my date time value is not empty. What should I do?

Comment: You don't actually need to have `new { Value = Model.CommunicationTime }` to display a Property's value. The Linq expression is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery datepicker then change your TextBoxFor like below:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CommunicationTime, new {@id = "yourdatepicker", @Value = Model.CommunicationTime.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")})

<script> 
   $('#yourdatepicker').datepicker();
</script>
```

Comment: When I try this one, the calender wouldnt shown. The pure text box shown only.

Comment: I tried also with type. At that time date time value wouldnt shown.

Comment: The CommunicationTime type is DateTime nullabel or just Datetime?

Comment: If you want to use razor syntax, this link may help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/237411/Html-5-Controls-for-ASP-Net-MVC

Comment: Make sure that your  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") is at the top of _layout.cshtml rather than the bottom. This tut will help. http://instinctcoder.com/asp-net-mvc-4-jquery-datepicker/

Comment: Java Script files are not loading properly, check java script error in browser after page loaded ...

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a date or datetime? As an HTML5 input type, datetime is only supported in Opera and Safari. Otherwise, you'd need to use jquery datepicker and a timepicker.

Answer (score 0):

You should change type to datetime like this : type = "datetime"

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CommunicationTime, new { Value = Model.CommunicationTime, type = "datetime" })
```